# Evaluate $\int\cos^3x\sin^2x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

My university mathematics is kind of poor. But as I am learning advanced mathematics this becomes a major shortcoming.

I tried to integrate
$\int$$\sin^3\theta$$\cos^2\theta$d$\theta$ = $\int$(-3$\cos^3\theta$$\sin$$\theta$d$\theta$)$\left(-\frac13\right)$$\sin^2\theta$
= $\int$$\left(-\frac13\right)$($\sin^2\theta$)d($\cos^3\theta$) = $\left(-\frac13\right)$($\sin^2\theta$$\cos^3\theta$) - $\left(-\frac13\right)$$\int$$\cos^3\theta$d$\sin^2\theta$ = $\left(-\frac13\right)$($\sin^2\theta$$\cos^3\theta$) - $\int$(-2)$\cos^4\theta$d$\theta$ = $\left(-\frac13\right)$($\sin^2\theta$$\cos^3\theta$) + $\left(\frac2{15}\right)$$\cos^5\theta$

But this certainly is wrong. Why?

Comment: Your very first equality: $$\int \sin^3\theta\cos^2\theta \,d\theta\stackrel{??}=\int\left(-3\cos^3\theta\sin\theta \,d\theta\right)\left(-\frac13\right)\sin^2\theta$$ Can you see you already have an extra power of $\;\cos\theta\;$ that wasn't there before?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003931/integrate-int-sin-x2-cos-x3-dx

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: And this won't be marked as a duplicate because it comes under the category of "Check my work"? Don't we have some procedure for dealing with these kinds of questions?

Answer (score 2):

This is a substitution. Note the odd power. Thus let $u=cos \theta$ so $du=-\sin \theta$

$$\int \sin^3 \theta \cos^2\theta d\theta=
\int (u^2-1)u^2 du$$

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way to solve this:
To find: $$\int \cos^3x\sin^2x~dx$$
First we need to observe that $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$ and $\cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$. We can now rewrite the integral as
$$\int \cos^3x(1-\cos^2x)dx=\int \cos^3x -\int \cos^5x$$
$$\Rightarrow \int \cos^3x(1-\cos^2x)dx=\int \frac{\cos 3x-3cosx}{4}dx-\int(\cos^3x)^2dx$$
Rewrite $\cos^3 x$ in the second integral and square the term. Can you continue from here?

EDIT: it is a wonder that no one pointed out my mistake.Breaking the integral into two parts we get
$$\int \cos^3 x~dx-\int cos^5 x~dx  $$
Substitute second formula in the first integral. For the second integral:
Rewrite $\cos^5 x$ as $\cos^3 x \cos^2x$. Use $\cos2x=\cos^2x-1$. Substitute the formulas and you will get
$$(\frac{\cos 3x-3cosx}{4})(\cos 2x+1)=\frac{\cos3x\cos2x+\cos3x-3\cos x\cos2x-3\cos x}{4}$$
The work is not over yet. Finally use the fact that $\cos A+\cos B=2\cos \frac{A+B}{2} \cos \frac{A-B}{2}$.
 Hence $\cos3x\cos2x=\frac{cos 5x+cos x}{2}$ and $\cos x \cos 2x=\frac{\cos3x+\cos x}{2}$. I am sure you can take care of the rest. Substitue and integrate.

Answer (score 1):

An idea: integration by parts:

$$\begin{align*}&u=\cos\theta\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,u'=-\sin\theta\\
&v'=\sin^3\theta\cos\theta\;\;\;v=\frac14\sin^4\theta\end{align*}$$

and thus

$$\int \sin^3\theta\ cos^2\theta\;d\theta=\frac14\sin^4\theta\cos\theta +\frac14\int \sin^5\theta\;d\theta$$

For the last integral above you can use one fo the known [reduction formulas](http://www.integraltec.com/math/math.php?f=sinPower.html)...or calculate it by yourself. It isn't really hard, but it's boring.

Other idea, perhaps faster and simpler:

$$\int\sin^3\theta\cos^2\theta\;d\theta\int\sin^3\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)\;d\theta=\int\left(\sin^3\theta-\sin^5\theta\right)\;d\theta$$

and again the reduction formula twice.